# Which algorithm to use for percentage features in my DV and IV, in regression?

Tags: python, statistics, regression, percentage, feature-extraction

I am using regression to analyze server data to find feature importance.

Some of my IVs (independent variables) or Xs are in percentages like % of time, % of cores, % of resource used, while others are in numbers like number of bytes, etc.

I standardized all my Xs with `(X-X_mean)/X_stddev`. (Am I wrong in doing so?)

Which algorithm should I use in Python in case my IVs are a mix of numeric and %s and I predict Y in the following cases:

> Case 1: Predict a continuous valued Y
>
> a.Will using a Lasso regression suffice?
>
> b. How do I interpret the X-coefficient if X is standardized and is a
>   numeric value?
>
> c. How do I interpret the X-coefficient if X is standardized and is a
>   %?
>
> Case 2: Predict a %-ed valued Y, like "% resource used".
>
> a. Should I use Beta-Regression? If so which package in Python offers
>   this?
>
> b. How do I interpret the X-coefficient if X is standardized and is a
>   numeric value?
>
> c. How do I interpret the X-coefficient if X is standardized and is a
>   %?

If I am wrong in standardizing the Xs which are % already, is it fine to use these numbers as 0.30 for 30% so that they fall within the range 0-1? So that means I do not standardize them, I will still standardize the other numeric IVs.

> Final Aim for both Cases 1 and 2:
>
> To find the % of impact of IVs on Y. 
>   e.g.: When X1 increases by 1 unit, Y increases by 21%

I understand from other posts that we can NEVER add up all coefficients to a total of 100 to assess the % of impact of each and every IV on the DV. I hope I am correct in this regard.

Comment: When you ask *"I standardized all my Xs (X-X_mean/X_stddev). (Am I wrong in doing so?)"*, you didn't say it was for regression. It depends on the classifier/regressor algorithm you use. For linear-regression-based algorithms (like lasso) or clustering, that is usually done. (An alternative standardization is `(X-X_mean)/(X_max-X_min)`. But for tree-based algorithms (RF/XGB/GBT) standardization is not necessary, you can just feed them the raw data.

Comment: See also: [DataScience.SE questions about 'standardize' and 'regression'](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=regression%20standardize). This is more on-topic over on DS.SE.

Comment: Thanks dear @smci , I had added the tags for "regression" , now I have edited my post for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question confuses some concepts and jumbles a lot of terminology. Essentially you're asking about **a) feature preprocessing for (linear) regression, b) the interpretability of linear regression coefficients, and c) sensitivity analysis (the effect of feature X_i on Y)**. But be careful because you're making a huge assumption that Y is linearly dependent on each X_i, see below.

1. Standardization is not an "algorithm", just a technique for preprocessing data.
2. **Standardization is needed for regression, but it is not needed for tree-based algorithms (RF/XGB/GBT)** - with those, you can feed in raw numeric features directly (percents, totals, whatever).
3. `(X-X_mean)/X_stddev` **is not standardization, it's normalization.**

   - (An alternative to that is (true) **standardization** which is: `(X-X_min)/(X_max-X_min)`, which transforms each variable into the range [0,1]; or you can transform to [0,1].
4. Last you ask about **sensitivity analysis in regression** : Can we directly interpret the regression coefficient for X_i as the sensitivity of Y on X_i?

   - Stop and think about your underlying linearity assumption in *"Final Aim for both cases 1 & 2: To find the % of impact of IVs on Y. Eg: When X1 increases by 1 unit, Y increases by 21%"*.
   - **you're assuming that the Dependent Variable has a linear relationship with each Independent Variable. But that is often not the case, it may be nonlinear**. For example, if you're looking at the effect of Age on Salary, you would typically see it increase up to 40s/50s, then decrease gradually, and when you hit retirement age (say 65), decrease sharply.
   - so, you would model the effect of Age on Salary as quadratic or higher-order polynomial, by throwing in Age^2 and maybe Age^3 terms (or else sometimes you might see `sqrt(X)`, `log(X)`, `log1p(X)`, `exp(X)` etc. terms. Anything that best captures the nonlinear relationship. You may also see variable-variable interaction terms, although regression strictly assumes variables are not correlated with each other.)
   - obviously, Age has a huge effect on Salary, but we would not measure the sensitivity of Salary to Age by combining the (absolute value of) coefficients of Age, Age^2, Age^3.
   - if we only had a linear term for Age, the single coefficient for Age would massively understate the influence of Age on Salary, it would net "average out" the strong positive relationship for the regime Age<40 versus the negative relationship for Age>50
5. So [the general answer to "Can we directly interpret the regression coefficient for X_i as the sensitivity of Y on X_i?" is **"Only if the relationship between Y and that X_i is linear, otherwise no"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_analysis#Regression_analysis).
6. **In general, a better and easier way to do sensitivity analysis (without assuming linear response, or needing standardization of % features) is tree-based algorithms (RF/XGB/GBT)** which generate **feature importances**.

   - As an aside, I understand your exercise tells you to use regression, but in general you get better faster feature-importance information from tree-based (RF/XGB), especially for a shallow tree (small value for max_depth, large value of nodesize e.g. >0.1% of training-set size). That's why people use it, even when their final goal is regression.

(Your question is would get better answers over at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), but it's fine to leave here on SO, there is a crossover).

Answer (score 1):

Having a mix of predictors doesn't matter for any form of regression, this will only change how you interpret the coefficients. What does matter, however, is the type/distribution of your Y variable

> Case 1: Predict a continuous valued Y
> a.Will using a Lasso regression suffice?

Regular OLS regression will work fine for this

> b. How do I interpret the X-coefficient if X is standardized and is a
> numeric value?

The interpretation of coefficients always follows a format like "for a 1 unit change in X, we expect an x-coefficient amount of change in Y, holding the other predictors constant"

Because you have standardized X, your unit is a standard deviation. So the interpretation will be "for a 1 standard deviation change in X, we expect an X-coefficient amount of change in Y..."

> c. How do I interpret the X-coefficient if X is standardized and is a
> %?

Same as above. You units are still standard deviations, despite it originally coming from a percentage

> Case 2: Predict a %-ed valued Y, like % resource used.
>
> a. Should I use Beta-Regression? If so which package in Python offers
> this?

This is tricky. The typical recommendation is to use something like binomial logistic regression when your Y outcome is a percentage.

> b. How do I interpret the X-coefficient if X is standardized and is a
> numeric value?
>
> c. How do I interpret the X-coefficient if X is standardized and is a
> %?

Same as interpretations above. But if you use logistic regression, they are in the units of log odds. I would recommend reading up on logistic regression to get a deeper sense of how this works

> If I am wrong in standardizing the Xs which are a % already , is it
> fine to use these numbers as 0.30 for 30% so that they fall within the
> range 0-1? So that means I do not standardize them, I will still
> standardize the other numeric IVs.

Standardizing is perfectly fine for variables in regression, but like I said, it changes your interpretation as your unit is now a standard deviation

> Final Aim for both cases 1 & 2:
>
> To find the % of impact of IVs on Y. Eg: When X1 increases by 1 unit,
> Y increases by 21%

If your Y is a percentage and you use something like OLS regression, then that is exactly how you would interpret the coefficients (for a 1 unit change in X1, Y changes by some percent)

Comment: Dear, Thank you for the detailed response , my Y% is actually not a success/total trials ,but a proportion like %of CPU time. So in this case how can I model this scenario in python ? I believe I can not use glm logistic binomial regression, am I right ?

Comment: Also, In Case 2: since Y can have only values between 0 and 1, the python algorithm I use should keep this range limit too..

Comment: Im not sure how you would do it in python as I mainly use R for this type of analysis, but a logistic regression would be correct for case 2 (especially because it retains that range limit between 0 and 1). a binomial logistic regression doesn't just have to be dichotomous, it can be used to represented success out of N trials. See here for an explanation: https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/when-to-use-logistic-regression-for-percentages-and-counts/

Comment: Dear @Simon , in the link you referred: This is my meaning of Y % (%of a resource used) :  Quoting "It’s a little bit different than a percentage of a mass quantity, like the percentage of the area of a Petri dish that is covered with mold. In the Petri dish example, there aren’t discrete trials, each of which could be a success or a failure. It’s just one mass and some measurable percentage of it is covered with mold."   So I feel I can not use a logistic regression for Case 2 where my Y is a % of resource used... and not a success out of some N trials.... please correct me if I am wrong ...

Comment: Hmm you might be right. I'm not sure what you would use in that case, maybe regular OLS regression would be OK there too, but I would check some diagnostic plots first in that case to make sure you haven't violated any assumptions of OLS

Comment: **No you can't interpret the regression coefficients as the "sensitivity of Y to X_i", unless you know the response is linear.** In general that's not a correct assumption. See my answer.